# I bought a used ECM off eBay for my vehicle. Same year, engine, options everything as mine. Do I still need to have it flashed to my car?

Tags: durango, hemi, electronic-control-module

I bought an ECM off eBay for my 2004 Durango, donor vehicle is the same year, same engine (5.7), same tire size, same submodel. I think the only difference is the mileage, Do I still need to have it flashed to mine?

Comment: Have you tried it connected to the vehicle?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: The minimum you'll probably need to do with it is get the VIN reprogrammed to your vehicle.